# How to ignore folder in just post_process while collectstatic django?

Tags: django, deployment

Is there any way to ignore a folder only for post_process() when running [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic)? Im running the following command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput -i libs
```

But the issue is that it ignores collecting the files from libs folder as well and I would like to collect the files but no execute post_process() for libs.

using --no-post-process ignores completely post_process(), so in our use case is not applicable.

Comment: Can't you just check inside `post_process` for paths that don't start with "lib/"?

Comment: I think that could be a solution, would it be customising post_process? or is it possible by command/parameters?

Comment: still no solution for this one :( ?